# XSL for-each only showing first record

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSL

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="DETAILS/PALLETDETAILS">
 <xsl:value-of select="PALLETCOUNTTOTAL"/>
 <xsl:for-each select="/DETAILS/PALLETDETAILS/PRODUCTDETAILS">
   <xsl:value-of select="PRODNUM"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="QUANTITY"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="BOXES"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

And the following XML

```
<DETAILS>
  <PALLETDETAILS>
    <PRODUCTDETAILS>
      <PRODNUM>123</PRODNUM>
      <QUANTITY>3000</QUANTITY>
      <BOXES>3</BOXES>
    </PRODUCTDETAILS>
    <PRODUCTDETAILS>
      <PRODNUM>1572</PRODNUM>
      <QUANTITY>1000</QUANTITY>
      <BOXES>1</BOXES>
    </PRODUCTDETAILS>
    <TOTALWEIGHT>25</TOTALWEIGHT>
    <TOTALBOXES>4</TOTALBOXES>
    <PALLETCOUNT>1</PALLETCOUNT>
    <PALLETCOUNTTOTAL>2</PALLETCOUNTTOTAL>
    <PALLETDETAILS>
      <PRODUCTDETAILS>
        <PRODNUM>456</PRODNUM>
        <QUANTITY>3000</QUANTITY>
        <BOXES>3</BOXES>
      </PRODUCTDETAILS>
      <PRODUCTDETAILS>
        <PRODNUM>1572</PRODNUM>
        <QUANTITY>1000</QUANTITY>
        <BOXES>1</BOXES>
      </PRODUCTDETAILS>
      <TOTALWEIGHT>25</TOTALWEIGHT>
      <TOTALBOXES>4</TOTALBOXES>
      <PALLETCOUNT>2</PALLETCOUNT>
      <PALLETCOUNTTOTAL>2</PALLETCOUNTTOTAL>
    </PALLETDETAILS>
  </PALLETDETAILS>
</DETAILS>
```

However when I run a transformation the XSL is only outputting the first pallet and completely disregarding the 2nd.
I've tried various alterations to the outer and inner for-each loop, but can't seem to get any different result.

edit:
Expected output should be

```
<palletcounttotal>2</palletcounttotal>
<prodnum>123</prodnum>
<quantity>3000</quantity>
<boxes>3</boxes>
<prodnum>1572</prodnum>
<quantity>1000</quantity>
<boxes>1</boxes>
<palletcounttotal>2</palletcounttotal>
<prodnum>456</prodnum>
<quantity>3000</quantity>
<boxes>3</boxes>
<prodnum>1572</prodnum>
<quantity>1000</quantity>
<boxes>1</boxes>
```

but instead I'm only getting

```
<palletcounttotal>2</palletcounttotal>
<prodnum>123</prodnum>
<quantity>3000</quantity>
<boxes>3</boxes>
<prodnum>1572</prodnum>
<quantity>1000</quantity>
<boxes>1</boxes>
```

Comment: This is confusing because your stylesheet does NOT produce the result you claim.

Comment: Please clarify if the desired output XML tags shall be converted to lower case.

Comment: The lowercase is on me, as I typed the expected results by hand as I'm not getting them.
I noticed that I forgot the palletcounttotal in the expected results too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

It is possible to implement what is needed by using one single loop.
I added a root element to make the output XML well-formed.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/DETAILS">
        <root>
            <xsl:copy-of select="PALLETDETAILS/PALLETDETAILS/PALLETCOUNTTOTAL"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="PALLETDETAILS//PRODUCTDETAILS/*">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<root>
  <PALLETCOUNTTOTAL>2</PALLETCOUNTTOTAL>
  <PRODNUM>123</PRODNUM>
  <QUANTITY>3000</QUANTITY>
  <BOXES>3</BOXES>
  <PRODNUM>1572</PRODNUM>
  <QUANTITY>1000</QUANTITY>
  <BOXES>1</BOXES>
  <PRODNUM>456</PRODNUM>
  <QUANTITY>3000</QUANTITY>
  <BOXES>3</BOXES>
  <PRODNUM>1572</PRODNUM>
  <QUANTITY>1000</QUANTITY>
  <BOXES>1</BOXES>
</root>
```

Comment: `<xsl:for-each select="PALLETDETAILS//PRODUCTDETAILS/*"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:for-each>` is a roundabout way to write `<xsl:copy-of select="PALLETDETAILS//PRODUCTDETAILS/*"/>`. Still, neither of these procuce the expected result:  `prodnum` is not the same as `PRODNUM`.

Comment: I used the loop to be prepared to lower case the element names. Let's wait for the OP reply.

Comment: <shrug> I waited. You didn't.

Answer (score 0):

The inner `for-each` is probably meant to be relative to the outer so e.g. `xsl:for-each select="PALLETDETAILS/PRODUCTDETAILS"` for the inner for-each might make more sense. But you haven't show us whether you want a flat result or if you want to keep the input nesting for the result output.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for quite a while, so either flat or nested would be a massive help.